# Finding all the roots for $x^3+2x=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to find all the roots for :

$$x^3+2x=0$$

I know how to find the real root which is $0$ but how about the imaginary root

Comment: Find... **where** ? Anywhere, one root is sure: zero. The rest are square roots of $\,-2\,$ ...

Comment: so @user72070  you are welcome,if you have any question just post here ok?good lucks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$x^3+2x=0\\x(x^2+2)=0\\x=0\quad\text{or}\quad x^2+2=0\\x=0\quad\text{or}\quad x^2=-2$$

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Use that
$$x^3 +2x=x(x^2 +2)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

take out  $x$ from brackets,you get

$x*(x^2+2)=0$

so you have  $x_1=0$  ,$x_2=\sqrt{-2}$  or it is equal to  $\sqrt{2}*i$

because $\sqrt{-2}=\sqrt{-1}*\sqrt{2}$

and  by definition of imaginary number $i$

$\sqrt{-1}=i$

also  $x_2$ is equal to it's conjugate or  $x_2=-\sqrt{2}*i$

let us write it more detail for  second case,in  general when discriminant is  negative we have complex roots,like $p+q*i$  and $p-q*i$

for this case

$x^2+2=0$

we have
$0+\sqrt{2}*i$  and  $0-\sqrt{2}*i$

Comment: $x_2=\pm i\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $x^3+2x=x(x^2+2)=x(x-\sqrt 2 i)(x+\sqrt 2 i)$.